# Where can I find information about Google Maps Single Search Box coverage?

Tags: google-maps, search, maps, local

Where can I find a complete list of countries where Google Maps supports the single search box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but the listing of the API coverage offered by Google Maps is at: [Google Maps API Coverage](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ah0xU81penP1cDlwZHdzYWkyaERNc0xrWHNvTTA1S1E&gid=0)